# Counting how many times football teams have won using a nested list

Tags: python, list, count, nested

I need to write a function that looks at a nested list with two teams and their game score respectively. The list contains multiple matches and I want the output to be a nested list with all the team names and how many games they won. The list looks like this:

```
L = [['Patriots', 'Giants', '3', '1'], ['Steelers', 'Patriots', '1', 2'], ['Giants', 'Steelers', '3', '5']]
```

So in the above list the first two elements are the team names and the third and fourth elements are the points they score in the match. However, the list is much larger than this and there are a lot more teams. The output would look something like this:

```
finalList = [['Patriots', 2], ['Giants', 0], ['Steelers', 1]]
```

because the Patriots won two games, Giants won zero games and Steelers won one game.

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work and I'm stuck.

```
def gamesWon():
    for i in L:
        count = 0
        if i[2]>i[3]:
            count += 1
            i.append(count)
```

Comment: Why don't you use finalList as a dictionary with name of team as key and  score as value: `finalList = {'Patriots': 2, 'Giants': 0}`?

Comment: I haven't learnt how to use dictionaries yet so I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: Remember **Zen of Python** by Tim Peters: **Flat is better than nested.**. Thus, use dictionaries instead of nested lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# initialize the result as a defaultdict with default value of 0
result = defaultdict(lambda : 0)   

for t1,t2,s1,s2 in L:
    if int(s1) > int(s2):
        result[t1] += 1
    elif int(s2) > int(s1):
        result[t2] += 1

result
# defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {'Patriots': 2, 'Steelers': 1})
```

Note that even though in the result, teams with zero score are missing, but if you call `result[team]`, it gives you zero.

Comment: This doesn't contain teams who never win!

Comment: @Julien That's true. But this defaultdict has 0 as default value, so teams that never win will always have 0 as value.

Comment: Sure but if you then pass the structure to someone who doesn't know all team names, the information is lost... and OP's list does contain all teams.

Comment: @Julien Makes sense. It depends on OP's actual use case then.

Comment: I should probably have stated that I haven't learnt how to use dictionaries yet, so I can't use them.

Comment: Then just re-invent the wheel: create you dict like structure with lists underneath... will be cumbersome and inefficient but it will work. Your problem *is exactly* building a dictionary!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [['Patriots', 'Giants', '3', '1'], ['Steelers', 'Patriots', '1', '2'], ['Giants', 'Steelers', '3', '5']]

D = defaultdict(int)

for match in L:
    team1, team2, score1, score2 = match
    D[team1] # make sure the team exist in the dict even if it never wins a match
    D[team2] # make sure the team exist in the dict even if it never wins a match
    if int(score1) > int(score2):
        D[team1] += 1
    if int(score2) > int(score1):
        D[team2] += 1
```

You can then convert `D` to a list easily if you absolutely need...

Comment: I should probably have stated that I haven't learnt how to use dictionaries yet, so I can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a `Counter`, which is dict-like:

```
import collections as ct

L = [
    ['Patriots', 'Giants', '3', '1'], 
    ['Steelers', 'Patriots', '1', '2'], 
    ['Giants', 'Steelers', '3', '5'],
    ['Giants', 'Patriots', '1', '1']                       # tie  
]    

def count_wins(games):
    """Return a counter of team wins, given a list of games."""
    c = ct.Counter()                                        
    for team1, team2, s1, s2 in games:
        c[team1] += 0
        c[team2] += 0
        if int(s1) == int(s2):
            continue
        elif int(s1) > int(s2):
            c[team1] += 1
        else:
            c[team2] += 1
    return c

season = count_wins(L)
season
# Counter({'Giants': 0, 'Patriots': 2, 'Steelers': 1})
```

---

The latter code gives a default of zero increments for new entries and handles ties:

```
L_tie = [['Cowboys', 'Packers', '3', '3']]
game = count_wins(L_tie)
game
# Counter({'Cowboys': 0, 'Packers': 0})
```

Counters have some useful methods for finding the top teams:

```
season.most_common(2)
# [('Patriots', 2), ('Steelers', 1)]
```

Counters are flexible.  You can update Counters easily:

```
season.update(game)
season
# Counter({'Cowboys': 0, 'Giants': 0, 'Packers': 0, 'Patriots': 2, 'Steelers': 1})
```

You can also [add (subtract and perform set operations with)](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html#arithmetic) other Counters:

```
L_last = [['49ers', 'Raiders', '7', '10'], ['Packers', 'Patriots', '3', '7']] 
last_season = count_wins(L_last)
season + last_season
# Counter({'Patriots': 3, 'Raiders': 1, 'Steelers': 1})
```

UPDATE: See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43906704/4531270) for a `Counter`/generator expression variant.

Answer (score 0):

```
ll = [['Patriots', 'Giants', '3', '1'], ['Steelers', 'Patriots', '1', '2'], ['Giants', 'Steelers', '3', '5']]

teamStatus = {}

for l in ll:
  team1,team2,team1_score,team2_score = l
  if team1 not in teamStatus:
      teamStatus[team1] = 0
  if team2 not in teamStatus:    
      teamStatus[team2] = 0

  if int(team1_score) > int(team2_score):
    teamStatus[team1] += 1 
  else:
    teamStatus[team2] += 1

print(teamStatus)
```

**RESULT**

```
{'Patriots': 2, 'Giants': 0, 'Steelers': 1}
```